# Running .NETPortable NUnit tests on linux with mono

Tags: mono, nunit

I have a xamarin PCL project with a an NUnit project.

I want to run the NUnit tests in the [mono-nunit](https://hub.docker.com/r/fela98/mono-nunit/) docker image.

I run the tests with:

```
nunit -framework=4.0 bin/Debug/MY_AppTests.dll
```

and get:

```
.NETPortable test assemblies are not yet supported by the engine
```

Is this final? Is there a way I can run .NETProtale tests assemblies in the mono-nunit image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not final, we will be adding Portable (or more likely .NET Standard) support into the engine soon, hopefully for the 3.7 release.

Meanwhile, switch your test project to an executable, add a reference to [NUnitLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitLite/) and add the following code to `program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return new AutoRun(typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .Execute(args, new ExtendedTextWrapper(Console.Out), Console.In);
    }
}
```

This will create self-executing tests. You can pass in most command line options that you would normally pass into the NUnit Console.

For more information, see [Testing .NET Core RC2 Using NUnit 3](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/05/18/testing-net-core-rc2-using-nunit-3/). Except for the .NET Core project format, the information is the same.

There is also some [documentation on NUnitLite](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner).